# Trouble understanding Visual Studio Code errors with source maps?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I'm pretty ignorant on this so forgive the very scattered information. I'm working on a discord bot and have a few modules that I've installed within my project. Today I loaded up the bot for testing in VS Code and lo and behold I see a bunch of weird errors that make no sense to me, and I have no idea what to do about them?

```
Debugger attached.
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/index.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/index.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/index.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/index.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/FsPromise.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/FsPromise.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/core.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/core.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/ReadStreamTokenizer.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/ReadStreamTokenizer.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/AbstractTokenizer.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/AbstractTokenizer.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/peek-readable/lib/index.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/peek-readable/lib/index.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/peek-readable/lib/EndOfFileStream.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/peek-readable/lib/EndOfFileStream.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/BufferTokenizer.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/BufferTokenizer.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/FileTokenizer.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/strtok3/lib/FileTokenizer.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/core.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/core.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ParserFactory.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ParserFactory.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/token-types/lib/index.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/token-types/lib/index.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/MetadataCollector.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/MetadataCollector.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/type.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/type.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/GenericTagTypes.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/GenericTagTypes.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/CombinedTagMapper.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/CombinedTagMapper.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v1/ID3v1TagMap.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v1/ID3v1TagMap.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/GenericTagMapper.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/GenericTagMapper.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v1/ID3v1Parser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v1/ID3v1Parser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/Util.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/Util.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/Windows1292Decoder.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/Windows1292Decoder.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/BasicParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/BasicParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/apev2/APEv2Parser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/apev2/APEv2Parser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/apev2/APEv2Token.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/apev2/APEv2Token.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/FourCC.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/FourCC.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/ID3v24TagMapper.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/ID3v24TagMapper.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/CaseInsensitiveTagMap.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/CaseInsensitiveTagMap.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/asf/AsfTagMapper.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/asf/AsfTagMapper.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/ID3v22TagMapper.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/ID3v22TagMapper.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/apev2/APEv2TagMapper.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/apev2/APEv2TagMapper.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/mp4/MP4TagMapper.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/mp4/MP4TagMapper.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/vorbis/VorbisTagMapper.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/vorbis/VorbisTagMapper.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/riff/RiffInfoTagMap.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/riff/RiffInfoTagMap.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/matroska/MatroskaTagMapper.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/matroska/MatroskaTagMapper.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/aiff/AiffParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/aiff/AiffParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/ID3v2Parser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/ID3v2Parser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/FrameParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/FrameParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/ID3v2Token.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/ID3v2Token.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/aiff/AiffToken.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/aiff/AiffToken.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/iff/index.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/iff/index.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/ID3Stream.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/ID3Stream.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/asf/AsfParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/asf/AsfParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/asf/GUID.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/asf/GUID.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/asf/AsfObject.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/asf/AsfObject.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/asf/AsfUtil.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/asf/AsfUtil.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/flac/FlacParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/flac/FlacParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/vorbis/Vorbis.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/vorbis/Vorbis.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/AbstractID3Parser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/id3v2/AbstractID3Parser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/vorbis/VorbisParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/vorbis/VorbisParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/vorbis/VorbisDecoder.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/vorbis/VorbisDecoder.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/mp4/MP4Parser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/mp4/MP4Parser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/mp4/Atom.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/mp4/Atom.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/mp4/AtomToken.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/mp4/AtomToken.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/mpeg/MpegParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/mpeg/MpegParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/mpeg/XingTag.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/mpeg/XingTag.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/musepack/index.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/musepack/index.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/musepack/sv8/MpcSv8Parser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/musepack/sv8/MpcSv8Parser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/musepack/sv8/StreamVersion8.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/musepack/sv8/StreamVersion8.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/musepack/sv7/MpcSv7Parser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/musepack/sv7/MpcSv7Parser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/musepack/sv7/StreamVersion7.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/musepack/sv7/StreamVersion7.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/musepack/sv7/BitReader.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/musepack/sv7/BitReader.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/OggParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/OggParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/opus/OpusParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/opus/OpusParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/opus/Opus.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/opus/Opus.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/speex/SpeexParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/speex/SpeexParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/speex/Speex.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/speex/Speex.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/theora/TheoraParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/theora/TheoraParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/theora/Theora.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/ogg/theora/Theora.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/riff/WaveParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/riff/WaveParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/riff/RiffChunk.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/riff/RiffChunk.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/wav/WaveChunk.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/wav/WaveChunk.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/wavpack/WavPackParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/wavpack/WavPackParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/wavpack/WavPackToken.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/wavpack/WavPackToken.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/dsf/DsfParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/dsf/DsfParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/dsf/DsfChunk.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/dsf/DsfChunk.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/dsdiff/DsdiffParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/dsdiff/DsdiffParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/dsdiff/DsdiffToken.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/dsdiff/DsdiffToken.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/matroska/MatroskaParser.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/matroska/MatroskaParser.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/matroska/types.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/matroska/types.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/matroska/MatroskaDtd.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/matroska/MatroskaDtd.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/RandomBufferReader.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/RandomBufferReader.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/lyrics3/Lyrics3.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/lyrics3/Lyrics3.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/RandomFileReader.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/music-metadata/lib/common/RandomFileReader.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/fecha/lib/fecha.umd.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/fecha/lib/fecha.umd.js.map'
```

I generally use the latest packages when it comes to my node modules so I'm not sure if something just went wrong with updating but I haven't the foggiest idea on what *any* of these are or even where to begin fixing them? I deleted the entire directory, cloned it, and reinstalled the packages with yarn but I'm still getting the same error messages?

Comment: same here, I was getting these this exact error as well as some other blockers in vs code insiders which I couldn't figure out and made me stop using it. Surprised to this bug/error in standard, unless there's something we've both got wrong with our projects

Comment: it doesn't prevent my bot from running at all, it just...spams these when the bot loads and then continues like nothing happened - which makes me more confused.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62871907/why-after-update-vscode-giving-this-error-could-not-read-source-map-for-no/63855003#63855003, I solved it by downgrading to previous month stable VSCode version.