# Why after update VSCode giving this error? Could not read source map for ... (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

My program was working before updating *Visual Studio Code*. After updating, Why am I get this error?

```
Could not read source map for file:///c:/Users/s.aytan/Desktop/node/new/Dashboard2/node_modules/fecha/lib/fecha.umd.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\s.aytan\Desktop\node\new\Dashboard2\node_modules\fecha\lib\fecha.umd.js.map'
```

Comment: See this bug: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102335

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try to add this property to the `.vscode\launch.json` file:

```
"resolveSourceMapLocations": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "!**/node_modules/**"
]
```

According to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102042#issuecomment-656402933), this should be configured as default in the next versions.

Comment: This is working but this time, Problem has " Property resolveSourceMapLocations is not allowed."

Comment: Are you getting this as warning in the editor? Apparently they did not add this field to the scheme, it is not terrible.

Comment: How do i add this to the scheme?

Comment: It will be in the next build, see this comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102042#issuecomment-656863279

Comment: still getting it, version 1.49.0

Comment: Just happened to me, version 1.49.0. "resolveSourcemapLocations" didn't address it, downgraded to v1.48.2 and it resolved problem.

Comment: I needed to change "type" from "node" to "pwd-node" for this to work.

Comment: @KitJohnson I believe that type is supposed to be `pwa-node`. When I set that as the type, adding `resolveSourceMapLocations` automatically populated the list with the values listed by @baruchiro

Comment: Added, still the same.

Answer (score 3):

you need to switch the launch type in `.vscode\launch.json` configuration from:

```
"type": "node",
```

to

```
"type": "pwa-node",
```

Answer (score -1):

Try installing an older version of VSCode, that solve this same issue here.

Comment: This comment should not be downvoted.  The updates to VS code seem poor at times and all too often the best solution is to not install newer versions.  VS code needs to do a better job testing.